# Stretchable UIImageView like viber profile picture view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to build a stretchable UIImageView just like image view showing the picture of user in Viber application. Is it some native control or we have to make our own custom control? How we can build the same profile view?

Comment: try adding a UIPinchGestureController onto the UIImageView

Comment: The Xcode tag should be restricted to trusted users...

Answer (score 0):

Chek out this projcet. and trying this one...

**[1]: https://github.com/spoletto/SPUserResizableView**

Hope it may helpful to you....

Comment: Its fine. but in viber, image does not stretches or changes it size. Only UIImageView size changes and when we leave mouse it goes back to its original position. Can we make a deto of that?